# How to determine if Android's BOOT_COMPLETED has occurred (not receiving it)

Tags: android

I am not trying to create a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver (and doing so would not solve my problem).

Is there a way to determine if BOOT_COMPLETED has occurred? I have a library which is being called before (as well as after) Android has finished booting, and I do not want my library to complete its request if the system has not finished booting. Setting up a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver in every application that may use this library is not a reasonable approach for several reasons.

Are there any Android calls I can make to determine if the device's boot has completed? It appears that there is a property, dev.bootcomplete, which I may have to use if no better method exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the only *official* way of achieving this is to create `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver.

I would advise you not to rely on properties, since they often are OEM specific. Otherwise you may end up with your application working on one Android model, but not another.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Setting up a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver in every application
```

I guess you mean to say you dont want BOOT_COMPLETED receiver in each activity .

Its very much possible.

You can register `BOOT_COMPLETED receiver` for `Activity A`.and once `Activity A` a gets broadcast it can notify other activities using sendBroadcast (custom broadcast).

To see how to use custom broadcast [look here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Comment: in my case, the other applications are not always known to me. I suppose I could send a sticky broadcast from a receiver I know will be present on production devices, and have my library check for this broadcast though; thanks for the idea!

Comment: Are you talking about applications or activities?

Comment: I am talking about applications. The code that uses my library may be in an Activity or a Service; I have no control there. The receiver might be set up dynamically (allowing it to be at the Activity or Service layer) or statically in the Manifest, but it's reasonable to expect only static registration since most Activities will not be running to install a dynamic receiver before BOOT_COMPLETED.